# finish() not finishing my activity

Tags: android, android-activity

in my Android app I've got two activities, lets say A and B. A is the main activity, and it calls Activity B like so:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), B.class);
A.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

And this works fine. The back button on the phone works to return to activity A, but I want to put a button on the UI as well. So I have a "Cancel" button in Activity B's layout file, and I have the following code in Activity B's java.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if (arg0.getId() == R.id.btn_cancel) {
        B.this.finish();
    }

}
```

However, clicking the button doesn't cause anything to happen at all. Any insight? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks very much guys. I realized I wasn't setting my button's OnClickListener. D'oh! I'm still new at this haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see if the button is actually working first.

Try with a simple Log.d(); and see if that outputs something in the lolcat

Answer (score 0):

`arg0.getId()` is clearly not equal to `R.id.byn_cancel`
just remove the `if` statement and only include `B.this.finish();`